# API to retrieve data filtered by datetime in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I'm trying to retrieve data filtered by datetime from database.

I'm trying something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{datetime}/GetDataByDateTime", Name = "GetDataByDateTime")]
    public List<StsStatistic> GetDataByDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        List<StsStatistic> statisticList = new List<StsStatistic>();

        try
        {
            using (Context db = new Context())
            {
                statisticList = db.StsStatistics.Where(x => x.StsDatetimeSent.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") == dateTime).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
            // TODO
            // Put logger
        }
        return statisticList;
    }
```

And Swagger gives me this message:

https://localhost:44310/api/Statistics/{datetime}/GetDataByDateTime

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-45fcb84500917c4e8478fb15fff8a230-650b85b5faaf414d-00",
  "errors": {
    "dateTime": [
      "The value '{datetime}' is not valid."
    ]
  }
}
```

Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: And what is the value of the `DateTime` you're submitting in the request?

Comment: what value to you send to API? Can you show us the request in postman? Second, see @marc_s answer to fix the code or change "DateTime dateTime" to "string dateTime" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameter `dateTime` is of type `DateTime` - and hopefully so is the column `StsDatetimeSent` - so then **why** are you converting this to a string before comparing??

```
using (fassi_ioc20Context db = new fassi_ioc20Context())
{
    statisticList = db.StsStatistics
                      .Where(x => x.StsDatetimeSent.Value == dateTime)
                      .ToList();
}
```

If those *both* are of type `DateTime` - then just **leave it that way** and compare the date time values directly! Stop always converting every date&time to string for no reason......

Comment: I don't think this is where the error is coming from. It's a 400 from model validation, so I think the format being submitted to the API from the client is unparseable.

Comment: it was a stupid error, i wasn't passing correctly the parameter dateTime. I need a vacation...Thank you guys for the patience